# UWP MVVM Observablecollection has updated but not reflected on UI

Tags: c#, windows, mvvm, uwp, windows-10

I am begginer to UWP and MVVM I try to bind my observablecollection to gridview control which successfully bind on page load and when bind command to button and from that button i am adding new item to my observablecollection then it is not reflected on UI don't know that is issue here but while debugging i can see that my collection has been updated please help

what i have tried is :

> 1. my view is

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Update" Grid.Row="12" Height="35" Grid.Column="0" Margin="90,15,0,0" Name="btnUpdate"   
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="141"  
            Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}" />
    <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dgvEmpList" Margin="0,0,480,457"
                       Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="12" Grid.Column="1" GridLinesVisibility="All"
                       AlternatingRowBackground="LightBlue"
                       HeadersVisibility="Column"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      >
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="UserId"            
        Binding="{Binding UserId}" 
         />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="FirstName"            
        Binding="{Binding FirstName}" 
         />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="LastName"            
        Binding="{Binding LastName}" 
         />

            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="City"

        Binding="{Binding City}" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="State"

        Binding="{Binding State}" />
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn 
        Header="Country"

        Binding="{Binding Country}" />




        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>

    </controls:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

> and my model is

```
public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int userId;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string city;
        private string state;
        private string country;
        public int UserId
        {
            get
            {
                return userId;
            }
            set
            {
                userId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UserId");
            }
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                firstName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                lastName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LastName");
            }
        }
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return city;
            }
            set
            {
                city = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("City");
            }
        }
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return state;
            }
            set
            {
                state = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("State");
            }
        }
        public string Country
        {
            get
            {
                return country;
            }
            set
            {
                country = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Country");
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members  

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

> and my viewmodel is

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand
    {
 private ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList { get; set; }
        private User selecteduser;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)

            {
                PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                this.PropertyChanged(this, args);
            }
        }
 public UserViewModel()
        {
            _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>
            {
                new User{UserId = 1,FirstName="Raj",LastName="Beniwal",City="Delhi",State="DEL",Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=2,FirstName="Mark",LastName="henry",City="New York", State="NY", Country="USA"},
                new User{UserId=3,FirstName="Mahesh",LastName="Chand",City="Philadelphia", State="PHL", Country="USA"},
                new User{UserId=4,FirstName="Vikash",LastName="Nanda",City="Noida", State="UP", Country="CANADA"},
                new User{UserId=5,FirstName="Harsh",LastName="Kumar",City="Ghaziabad", State="UP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=6,FirstName="Reetesh",LastName="Tomar",City="Mumbai", State="MP", Country="INDIA"},
                new User{UserId=7,FirstName="Deven",LastName="Verma",City="Palwal", State="HP", Country="ENGLAND"},
                new User{UserId=8,FirstName="Ravi",LastName="Taneja",City="Delhi", State="DEL", Country="INDIA"}
            };


        }
public User SelectedUser
        {
            get
            {
                return selecteduser;
            }
            set
            {
                selecteduser = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedUser");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<User> Users
        {
            get
            { return _UsersList; }
            set
            {
                _UsersList = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Users");
            }
        }
 private ICommand mUpdater;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }



        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {

            _UsersList.Add(
                new User
                {
                    FirstName = "ABC",
                    LastName = "XYZ",
                    City = "TEST",
                    Country = "TESTREST",
                    State = "GUJRAT",
                    UserId = 9

                });



        }
        public ICommand UpdateCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (mUpdater == null)
                    mUpdater = new UserViewModel();
                return mUpdater;
            }
            set
            {
                mUpdater = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

in viewmodel when button clicks it goes to canexecute() then execute() and onexecute() my Observablecollection has updated from 8 items to 9 items but it not shows in UI

> One more question is if i want pass dynamic values to that
>   ObservableCollection to Add new item then how can i do that

Comment: Observable collection is a list which has special features like when you add a new item it will notify the UI there is change so it will reflect in UI. I dont think you need to assign `Users= _Userlist` as from the get its intended to provide the private

Comment: yes i have removed that  Users = _UsersList;
            Message msg = new Message(); but still it's not working

Comment: can you update the source code with this change. and also remove the assignment `Users = _Userlist`

Comment: yes now you can see that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occurs on ICommand, the ICommand you are using is not recommended. It's better to create a command class inherited from ICommand. First, you can follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.icommand) to create a RelayCommand and then create UpdateCommand property that type is RelayCommand.

```
public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList { get; set; }
        private User selecteduser;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)

            {
                PropertyChangedEventArgs args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                this.PropertyChanged(this, args);
            }
        }
        public UserViewModel()
        {
            ......
            UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateCustomer);
        }
        ......
        public RelayCommand UpdateCommand { get; set; }

        public void UpdateCustomer()
        {
            Users.Add(
                new User
                {
                    FirstName = "ABC",
                    LastName = "XYZ",
                    City = "TEST",
                    Country = "TESTREST",
                    State = "GUJRAT",
                    UserId = 9

                });
        }

    }
```

**Update:**

Just take TextBox as a simple example, you can use CommandParameter to bind the Text of TextBox.

.xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Width="300"></TextBox>
<Button ......  Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}"  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyTextBox,Path=Text}"/>
```

Since the parameters are passed in, the writing of RelayCommand also needs to be changed accordingly.

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;
        private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> updateCustomer)
        {
            _execute = updateCustomer;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }

        public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            var handler = CanExecuteChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        ......
        public void UpdateCustomer(object parameter)
        {
            //add Users

        }

    }
```

Comment: i have one more question i am try to show data from gridview to controls like textbox,combobox data show in textbox but in combobox data not reflected combobox doesnot have itemsource just have static item list

Comment: For your edit about "pass dynamic values", do you mean you want to pass value when you click the button? If it is, you can use CommandParameter to pass the value.

Comment: i have controls like textbox and combobox i want pass user entered value to this command when user click button

Comment: UpdateCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateCustomer); what i have to pass in parameter

Comment: You don't need to pass any parameter, just pass the method to RelayCommand is OK.

Comment: it gives me error cannot convert from 'method group' to Action

Comment: Have you replaced the RelayCommand with the new one I updated in answer? The original RelayCommand can only be passed a method with no parameters.

Comment: yes i have changed all that things but still it gives me error

Comment: I used your code and created a simple sample by adding TextBlock, here is the [link](https://github.com/wcj233/MVVM_Sample). You can download it to check, clean and build the project.

Comment: thanks a lot for your efforts but what if i have multiple textboxes i have bind all textbox on button commandparameter ?

Comment: From your new post, you said you have achieved this for multiple textboxes right?

Comment: yes i have done for textboxes but combobox seems to be different can you post answer for combobox

Comment: For that question, my colleague will help you to solve it.